# Proxy server client detection in Linux

Tags: linux, proxy, redhat, squid, rhel6

Is there any way to find out the clients connected to the proxy server in redhat linux ? squid is configured in the server and i need the host name of the machines connected to the proxy server ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the IP address and the port number of your proxy, that's typically 0.0.0.0:3128 or 0.0.0.0:8080 for TCP v4. Then, at the proxy host do:

```
netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | grep PROXY_PORT
```

Comment: i know the ip adress of the proxy server , is there any way to list all the clients connected through this proxy server

Comment: With the command I wrote above, you get a list of all connections to the proxy. Then you can see, the connections with the local IP is the IP of your server - are your clients. So, in this way you will see all IPs of all your connected clients.

Comment: Thanks it is working i am getting the ip information  , can i get the host name details

Comment: Yes, just use `netstat -a` instead (omitting -n option). It will expose IPs with their host names.

Comment: i am afraid it is taking too long time , is it like that ?

Comment: Command works fine but it did not list any host-name , but if i put the -an i am getting lot of ip's

Comment: Yes, because your system needs to resolve each IP address. Thus for each of them, your system seems communicating with the DNS server what takes communication time. If you put all of them into /etc/hosts it will be very fast, but then you have a local definition of the link IP - hostname.

Comment: i can list the ips not host name

Comment: What do you get with `netstat -a | grep...` ?

Comment: Nothing i got , but i got all the ips when i put netstat -an